# Is there a simple way to list all FHIR resources that exist using the FHIR package in python?

Tags: python, hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I have been using the following code to import all sub-modules in the `fhir.resources` package to list the standard resource names that exist for `FHIR`, but I realize this is a poor way to do it, and that silly peripheral module names are thrown in (like `fhir.resources.fhirreference`) which make this way of doing it objectively wrong. What might be the correct way to list all FHIR Resource names?

```
import os
import pkgutil
import fhir.resources
        
def list_resource_types():
    path = os.path.dirname(fhir.resources.__file__)
    types = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([path])]
    for i in sorted(i for i in types if i.lower()==i):
        print(i)
```

Thanks! ~Will

Comment: Have you just considered copying the names from the HL7 spec?  https://www.hl7.org/fhir/resourcelist.html.  (Alphabetical tab is probably easiest)

Comment: given the dynamic and evolving nature of the fhir standard, i dont entirely feel comfortable with this approach

Comment: The set of resources available in a given release is fixed - and new releases only come out ever 2-3 years.  If you want to keep up with the CI build, then something programatic would be needed - but the reality is that that list could change at any time, and in theory could change multiple times in a single day.  For 'real' use, you'd at minimum need to tie yourself to a connectathon or ballot snapshot, and those only come out 3-4 times per year max.